# Parse Dataframe string column into Street, City, State & Zip code

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I am trying to break up the following fixed string into several columns as  street ,city, state & zip code.  Is it possible to do this in SQLDF via the INSTR & Subtr method?

Sample Address String.  The difficult part is the NV and zip code parsing.

```
727 Wright Brothers Ln, Las Vegas, NV 89119, USA
```

I am able to parse the city/street information using sqldf/instr but unable to parse the final two values for state/zip code

```
parsed_tweetAddressdf <- sqldf("SELECT lon, lat, result, substr(result,0,instr(result,',')) AS street, substr(result,instr(result,',')+1,instr(result,',')-1) AS city from tweetAddressdf")
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?  _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: desired out put is '727 Wright Brothers Ln' as street, las vegas as city, NV as state, and 89119 as zipcode.  Trying to use sqldf & instr/substr functions in order to parse out the text between each comma into separate fields.

Comment: updated body of the initial question

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier using a regular expression (this can easily capture the fact that for example a state code is two letters and a zip code is 5 numbers)

Comment: If you post the results of `dput(head(parsed_tweetAddressdf))` there might be some hope, but at the moment you are the only one who can run that code with any possibility of getting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  They all use `instr` and `substr` as required by the question although the third also writes out the data and reads it back in (in addition to using `instr` and `substr`).  Notes at the end point out that it is also easy to do this in plain R or using `read.pattern` in gsubfn.

**1) Assume state, zip and country fields are fixed width** With only one sample record it is impossible to know what your general case is but if we assume that every record ends in `SS ZZZZZ, USA` where SS is the two letter state abbreviation and ZZZZZ is a 5 digit zip then this works:

```
DF <- data.frame(v = "727 Wright Brothers Ln, Las Vegas, NV 89119, USA")

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select 
  substr(v, 0, instr(v, ',')) street,
  substr(v, instr(v, ',') + 2, length(v) - 16 - instr(v, ',')) city,
  substr(v, -13, 2) state,
  substr(v, -10, 5) zip
 from DF")
```

giving:

```
                  street      city state   zip
1 727 Wright Brothers Ln Las Vegas    NV 89119
```

**2) Separate strictly based on commas (except state/zip)** This approach avoids certain assumptions in (1) at the expense of additional complication.  It takes the first two comma separated fields, the 2 character state and everything after that to the next comma as the zip.

It uses a triple nested select.  The innermost select denoted `a` parses the input string into: `street` and `a.rest`.  The next one proceeding outward denoted `b` returns the `street` already parsed from `a`, and parses `a.rest` into `city` and the `b.rest`.  The outermost one returns the `street` and `city` already parsed plus it returns the two state characters in `b.rest` and everything beyond them in `b.rest` to the next comma as `zip`.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("
  select
    street,
    city,
    substr(b.rest, 1, 2) state,
    substr(b.rest, 4, instr(b.rest, ',') - 4) zip
  from (
    select 
      street, 
      substr(a.rest, 0, instr(a.rest, ',')) city,
      substr(a.rest, instr(a.rest, ',') + 2) rest 
    from (select 
            substr(v, 0, instr(v, ',')) street,
            substr(v, instr(v, ',') + 2) rest
    from DF) a) b
")
```

giving:

```
                  street      city state   zip
1 727 Wright Brothers Ln Las Vegas    NV 89119
```

**3) read.csv.sql** If it's OK to write it out and read it back in then we can use `read.csv.sql`, a wrapper around `sqldf`.  Although the question did not ask for it, this one also parses out the country:

```
write.table(DF, "addresses.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, 
            sep = ",", quote = FALSE)

read.csv.sql("addresses.csv", header = FALSE, sql = 
       "select V1 street, 
               V2 city, 
               substr(V3, 2, 2) state, 
               substr(V3, 4) zip, 
               V4 country 
        from file")
```

giving:

```
                  street       city state    zip country
1 727 Wright Brothers Ln  Las Vegas    NV  89119     USA
```

**Note 1:** This is also easy in plain R.

```
dd <- read.table(text = as.character(DF$v), sep = ",",
 col.names = c("street", "city", "state_zip", "country"))

transform(dd, 
              state = substring(state_zip, 2, 3), 
              zip = substring(state_zip, 4))[c(1, 2, 5, 6, 4)]
```

giving:

```
                  street       city state    zip country
1 727 Wright Brothers Ln  Las Vegas    NV  89119     USA
```

**Note 2:** It is even easier using `read.pattern` from gsubfn:

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "(.*), (.*), (..) (.*), (.*)"
read.pattern(text = as.character(DF$v), pattern = pat, 
   col.names = c("street", "city", "state", "zip", "country"))
```

giving:

```
                  street      city state   zip country
1 727 Wright Brothers Ln Las Vegas    NV 89119     USA
```

Comment: Added solutions and notes.